# How to run my python program with -m (full path)?

Tags: python, module, execution

I have a structure similar to this:

```
/home/user/nginx_http/
├── nginx_http
│   ├── common
│   │   ├── autodiscovery.py
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __main__.py
│   ├── nginx_http.py
├── README.rst
└── setup.py
```

When I'm in the /home/user/nginx_http folder and I run this:

```
python -m nginx_http
```

it works fine. But soon as I try to run it with full path it gives me an error;

```
python -m /home/user/nginx_http/nginx_http

/bin/python: Import by filename is not supported.; '/home/user/nginx_http/nginx_http' is a package and cannot be directly executed
```

I want to run my python program as a cronjob which would require the full path. The two options I wanted clarification on:

1. Should I consider moving my python program into python's module folder?

   /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages
2. Or should I set PYTHONPATH env to the location of /home/user/nginx_http. Will that break anything as far as other modules are concerned?

Thanks.

Comment: `python -m python -m`?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ edited, that was a typo